# Codesign (OSX): How to fix "unknown error -1009"?

Tags: macos, codesign

My already working command line call of `codesign`:

```
codesign -s <user> /path/to/app
```

has suddenly stopped working and outputs:

```
<app>: unknown error -1009=fffffffffffffc0f
```

What might cause this and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier for us if you posted that actual code that produces the error?

Comment: I was already able to fix the problem, but added this question here to help someone else (or even myself) in the future :) Anyway, maybe there are other possible issues which codesign fail with cryptic error codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS server was not properly configured, as the machine had been moved to another location. After fixing the network settings, it started working again.